# How do you add an exclusion using covselect?

Tags: bullseye

Examples I have been able to find suggest the following for an exclusion:

```
covselect --add \!/usr/src/thing/to/exclude
```

However, when I do this, and list my inclusions, I get:

```
BullseyeCoverage Select Regions 8.8.9 Linux-x64 License 9395 
Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2013
include folder /usr/src/
include folder /!/usr/src/thing/to/exclude/
```

?

Comment: Try to wrap the source you'd like to exclude with '  '. For example:
`covselect --add '\!/usr/src/thing/to/exclude'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that escaping the exclamation mark is only necessary for interactive bash shells.  When I put this into a script, the escape became literal and covselect was given the `\` as a path separator, which was then converted into `/`.  By removing the `!` escaping in the script, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems that the missing **/** at the end of the path was the problem.

Instead of for example

```
covselect --add '!**/usr/include'
```

put

```
covselect --add '!**/usr/include/'
```