# Exclude folder from Bullseye code coverage

Tags: bullseye

I want to remove some folders from my .cov file after coverage. My script that run coverage is not in the same folder as src.

I have followed couple of already existing stack [answer](https://#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459972/how-do-you-add-an-exclusion-using-covselect) but they seem not to work. I have already tried

```
covselect --file "%COVFILE%" --add \/src/bin/qwerty/ 

covselect --file "%COVFILE%" --add \../../src/bin/qwerty/ 

covselect --file "%COVFILE%" --remove ../../src/bin/qwerty/

covselect --file "%COVFILE%" --remove /src/bin/qwerty/
```

but no luck so far. I cannot find any information in Bullseye documentation. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it here: https://www.bullseye.com/help/build-exclude.html. So the pattern I finally used is as follows:

```
covselect --file "%COVFILE%" --add !**/src/bin/qwerty/
```

Where ** is a wildcard.